# PFR (preflop raise) statistics calculation with raise + 4bet in one single hand

Tags: statistics, pre-flop, raise, pokertracker, hud

Say you have played only 3 hands.

1 of them was when you were SB
1 of them was when you were BB
1 of them was when you were at Button

You folded when you were SB and BB.

It was only when you were at Button which you voluntarily put in the pot.
--> You opened by a raise
--> 1 opponent re-raised and all else folded (3-bet)
--> you re-raise again (4-bet)
--> your opponent calls

In this situation
Your VPIP=100% because you voluntarily put into the pot once out of 1 hand (excluding when you were SB and BB).
And your PFR=200% right? because you raised TWICE out of 1 hand played (raise and 4-bet)

Or no matter how many times you re-raise in a single hand, does it count as 1 Pre=flop raise?

Please let me know

Answer (score 3):

Your VP would still be 33% as you could have raised/called when you were in SB and BB - the tracker will only exclude walks where action was folded round to your BB.

As for the PFR, this generally means 2-bets so will also be 33% given you raised once out of three hands where you had the option to. Your 3-bet and 4-bet stats are recorded separately and should be 0% and 100% in your case.